# How to set Headers if I am using responde.sendRedirect

Tags: java, servlets, apache-httpclient-4.x

Previous scenario:-
User logins through Portal and user clicks on some link, the portal sends the request which contains Headers(user name) to reporting server to retrieve report .

Current Scenario:-
The portal was re-written and Headers are now being in JSON format, the Header values through which the authentication was being done is named in a different way. We thought to intercept the request and rearrange the Headers in a way how the reporting server reads so that request can go through.

We thought of  deploying this new Interceptor application in a new Tomcat server on the same box where Reporting server is , and I cannot use RequestDispatcher.forward , and sendRedirect if I use nullifies any Header values which I add before doing sendRedirect as browser will issue a new request.

I tried using HttpClient , to open a new Http connection to reporting server with adding Header values , but when I check the same in Fiddler or HTTP Header spy in my chrome browser I cannot see any Header values in the client request object. And I am trying to capture the response object from reporting server and set the same in my original request , and set that in the original response object in my servlet to push to client browser. But as my Header values are not getting set in HTTPClient Post request the request is never fulfilled.

Below is the same code for creating HTTPClient from my interceptor servlet.

---

```
    String url = "someurl";
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); 
//HttpGet get = new HttpGet();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
try {
    String smUser = "<user name>";
    String grps = "<some values>";
    post.addHeader(<headerKey1>,<smUser>);
    post.addHeader(<headerkey2>, grps);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(    
    response.getEntity().getContent()));
    response.getEntity().getContent();
    String inputLine; 
    StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = buff.readLine()) != null) { 
        html.append(inputLine); 
    }
    buff.close();
    System.out.println("URL Content... \n" + html.toString());
```

---

I know I can use url rewritting , but that is not an option , let me know if there is any other way through which my interceptor can change the Header values and pass the request to reporting server , so that user can access reports.

Answer (score 0):

I alse was blockd by this issue. Code like below, but the header I added hasn't been sent to target service. By the way,  there're two different services

```
response.setHeader(key, value)
response.sendRedirect(target_url)
```